# Merge duplicate (row group) column cells

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016

```
ID| Date1      | Date 2     |Total
-----------------------------------
1 | 15/02/2017 |02/02/2017  | 3  |
-----------------------------------
1 | 15/02/2017 |05/08/2017  | 3  |
-----------------------------------
1 | 15/02/2017 |12/12/2017  | 3  |
-----------------------------------
2 | 12/05/2017 |07/08/2017  | 2  |
-----------------------------------
2 | 12/05/2017 |10/08/2017  | 2  |
```

---

I have a table that is displaying data like above. I'm grouping that data on "ID" column. Values for Columns "**Date1**" & "**Total**" for a particular "**ID**" are the same but "**Date2**" value can be different in a given group.

How can i merge the cells across rows when the values are the same such that it displays like below?

```
 ID| Date1      | Date 2     |Total
-----------------------------------
1 | 15/02/2017 |02/02/2017  | 3  |
--|            |------------|    |
1 |            |05/08/2017  |    |
--|            |------------|    |
1 |            |12/12/2017  |    |
---------------------------------|
2 | 12/05/2017 |07/08/2017  | 2  |
--|            |------------|    |
2 |            |10/08/2017  |    |
```

---

I did manage to find that "HideDuplicates" TextBox property, but while that will suppress the repetition of the cell values in adjacent rows it does not merge those duplicate cells down the column across rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its difficult to tell how the report is setup in terms of groups etc without seeing the design, but this is pretty simple to do from scratch.

Start with a simple table with just your detail rows, no grouping. Then right-click the detail row in the row group panel under the main report design area. Choose Add Group -> Parent Group
Choose your Date1 field in the group by drop down . Click OK and you're done.