# How to properly merge duplicate column cells in Tablix (using Previous () function)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016

```
=iif(Fields!Case_ID.Value = Previous(Fields!Case_ID.Value), True, False)
```

In Atablix, am Merging duplicate (row group) column cells with the above expression.
I do this through right clicking the textbox in the column i want to merge duplicate cells, going to textbox properties, Visibility and then "show or hide based on expression".

This seems to work (partially) because it doesn't merge the first cell (the cell with the first occurrence of the duplicate values).

For example, If a row group has duplicates in 4 rows, it only merges cells in rows 2-4. Row one's cell is not merged with rows 2,3 & 4.

Below is an example of what it does

```
ID| Date1      | Date 2     |Total
-----------------------------------
1 | 15/02/2017 |02/02/2017  | 3  |
--|------------|------------|----|
1 |            |05/08/2017  |    |
--|            |------------|----|
1 |            |12/12/2017  |    |
---------------------------------|
2 | 12/05/2017 |07/08/2017  | 2  |
--|------------|------------|----|
2 |            |10/08/2017  |    |
```

How can i make sure that the merging works as below

```
ID| Date1      | Date 2     |Total
-----------------------------------
1 | 15/02/2017 |02/02/2017  | 3  |
--|            |------------|----|
1 |            |05/08/2017  |    |
--|            |------------|----|
1 |            |12/12/2017  |    |
---------------------------------|
2 | 12/05/2017 |07/08/2017  | 2  |
--|            |------------|----|
2 |            |10/08/2017  |    |
--|------------|------------|----|
```

Comment: they both look identical. Did you read my response to your very similar question here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002542/merge-duplicate-row-group-column-cells/49009796#49009796

Comment: how about make Date1 a child group if ID (you really should group by ID as well)? Then you won't have to worry about merging anything..Going purely by what your desired result and it's data looks like..